windows keyboard shortcut not work if keystrokes are sent by PowerShell
Trying to open "Indexing options" -> "Advanced options" -> tab "File Types" programmatically, using PowerShell command:
powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process 'rundll32.exe' -ArgumentList 'shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL', 'srchadmin.dll'; Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500; Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('d'); Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^{TAB}')"
It opens "Indexing options" window, then "Advanced options" window, but doesn't switch focus to second tab "File Types". When pressing CTRL+TAB manually, it switches tab view successfully.
Why this does not react to PowerShell sending ^{TAB} keystrokes? Am I doing something wrong?
Windows 10.0.19045.4894 64bit

Works fine for me, if I understand what you need in the 1st place. I'd recommend using Google Translate instead as this grammar is not too readable.

EFL, but what problem with understandibility of my question? Not complain, just wonder to improove next time meybe.
By topic: it means command activate TAB "File Types" successfully at its end? what is your windows version?

Windows 10. As I said, grammar. E.g. the whole 2nd sentence uses random tenses and verb forms. I assume "DO NOT" is "doesn't", for instance, but can't be sure.

ok, you are right. thanks for comment
